# How to do continuous Fourier transform?

Tags: fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

I want to do a Fourier transform to the below function by *Mathematica*. How can I do it? Here $c$, $d$, $a$, $L$ are constants.

$$
  w(r)= 
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      -\frac{c}{\epsilon r} & r> L \\
      -\frac{c}{\epsilon d}\left[\frac{a}{r}-\ln\left(\frac{r}{L}\right)\right] & a < r\leq L \\
      -\frac{c}{\epsilon d}\left[\ln\left(\frac{a}{L}\right)\right] & r \leq a \\
\end{array} 
\right. 
$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like Mathematica can do this.  Define something like this (I've simplified your version slightly)

```
w[r_] := Piecewise[{{-1/r, r > L}, {-1/d (a/r - Log[r/L]), 
    a < r <= L}, {-1/d Log[a/L], r <= a}}]
```

Mathematica will return a continuous Fourier transform

```
Assuming[0 < a < L, FourierTransform[w[r], r, k]]
```

I suggest you check the help for `FourierTransform` to ensure that the definition used is the one you want.

Comment: Thank you @mikado! Is this  'Assuming[0 < a < L, FourierTransform[w[r], r, k]]' code only for the travel from 0 to L,  exclude the r>L and r<= L?

Comment: No, I'm just saying that `a` is positive and less than `L`